# JB Full Width Slider

Tags: jquery

I am using JB Full width slider, this is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            JBFWS = new JBFWS();
            JBFWS.init({
                /* Slider Width & Height */
                width            : "100%",
                height           : "430px",

                /* Buttons settings */
                showBigButtons   : 1,  /* 0 - Hide, 1 - Show */
                showSmallButtons : 1,  /* 0 - Hide, 1 - Show */

                /* Main Slide */
                slideSpeed       : 1000, /* miliseconds */
                slideEffect      : "easeInOutExpo",

                /* Secondary Slide */
                slideDelay       : 600,  /* miliseconds. 0 - Off */
                slideSpeed2      : 1000, /* miliseconds. 0 - Off */
                slideEffect2     : "easeOutExpo",

                /* Drag Slide */
                dragSlide        : 1, /* 0 - Off, 1 - On */

                /* Auto Slide */
                autoSlide        : 0,   /* 0 - Off, 1 - On */
                autoSlideDelay   : 6000 /* miliseconds */   
            });
        });
```

How would I call this, but then later on set dragSlide to 0 if a link is clicked or a function is called?

Comment: Can you post a link to the API?

Comment: It's a paid jQuery script from CodeCanyon